# When appending div with an object, [object, Object] appears and not the actual input

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I have a for of loop that has 3 event listeners on links from a drop down menu. The first clears the div with the id 'kittyBox', the second adds an object to the div 'kittyBox', the third closes the menu.

My problem is that instead of the actual input of the object appearing, [object, Object] appears. How do I get the actual input to appear?

```
let kittyBox = document.getElementById('kittyBox')

function clearContainer() { kittyBox.innerHTML = '' }

function addBoo() { kittyBox.append(boo) }

class Cat {
  constructor(name, source) {
    this.box = document.createElement('div');
    kittyBox.append(this.box);
    this.header = document.createElement('h1');
    this.header.innerHTML = name;
    this.photo = new Image(400, 400);
    this.photo.src = source;
    this.count = document.createElement('span');
    this.box.append(this.header, this.photo);
    this.header.append(this.count);
    this.photo.onclick = counter;
    function counter() {
      score++;
      document.querySelector('span').textContent = ` ` + score;
    }
  }
}

let boo = new Cat('Boo', './img/boo.jpg')

for (let link of links) {
   link.addEventListener('click', clearContainer)
   link.addEventListener('click', () => { if (links[0]) { addBoo() } }
   link.addEventListener('click', () => menu.classList.toggle('slide-menu'))
```

I would like boo(div, h1, and image) to appear.

Comment: You have to append `boo.box` as far as I can tell. (since `boo` isn't an `HTMLElement`, the browser calls `.toString()` on it, which results in `[object Object]`)

Comment: Also, use `appendChild` as opposed to `append` to allow the runtime to catch such errors for you! e.g.: "Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'."

Answer (score 0):

the `append()` method inserts a set of `Node` ob jects or `DOMString` objects. In your case, you will have to create HTML elements of the object. Then append the newly created HTML elements to the `kittyBox` element.

For example:

```
const catElem = document.createElement("div");
const catImg = document.createElement("img");
catImg.src = boo.photo.src;
catElem.append(catImg);
kittyBox.append(catElem);
```